# Not able to create user defined tables automatically in Code First Approach using PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to create the tables using code first approach with postgresql database. My DB context is below.While doing migration i am getting the below error.

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'AspNetUser.Projects' of type 'ICollection'. Either
>   manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
>   '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.

```
 public class TaskPlannerDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Story> Stories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Epic> Epics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Favourite> Favourites { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProjectPermission> ProjectPermission { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Theme> Themes { get; set; }
        public TaskPlannerDbContext(DbContextOptions<TaskPlannerDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder); 

            builder.Entity<Project>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ProjectId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.AspNetUser)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Projects)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedBy)
                    .HasForeignKey(a => a.Owner)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectCreatedBy");
            });

            builder.Entity<Story>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.StoryId);


                entity.HasOne(d => d.AspNetUser)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Stories)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedBy)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_StoryCreatedBy");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Stories)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_StoryProjectId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Epic)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Stories)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.EpicId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_StoryEpicId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Theme)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Stories)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ThemeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_StoryThemeId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Priority)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Stories)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PriorityId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_StoryPriorityId");
            });

            builder.Entity<Epic>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.EpicId);


                entity.HasOne(d => d.AspNetUser)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Epics)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedBy)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_EpicCreatedBy");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Epics)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_EpicProjectId");
            });

            builder.Entity<Favourite>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.FavouriteId); 

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Favourites)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_FavouriteProjectId");
            });

            builder.Entity<Priority>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.PriorityId);



                entity.HasOne(d => d.AspNetUser)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Priorities)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedBy)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_PriorityCreatedBy");
            });
            builder.Entity<ProjectPermission>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.PermissionId);


                entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                    .WithMany(p => p.ProjectPermissions)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ProjectPermissionProjectId");
            });

            builder.Entity<Theme>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ThemeId);


                entity.HasOne(d => d.AspNetUser)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Themes)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedBy)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ThemesCreatedBy");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Themes)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ThemesProjectId");
            });     
        }
    }
```